# Get-AzureWebSite : Requested value 'PremiumV2' was not found

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I added a new Premium V2 app service plan. Now when running Get-AzureWebSite in PowerShell I'm getting the following error message:

```
get-azurewebsite : Requested value 'PremiumV2' was not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-azurewebsite
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureWebsite], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.GetAzureWebsiteCommand
```

What is the error about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old CmdLets are no longer well supported, and don't know about new features like Premium V2.

Try using the ARM based CmdLets instead, like `Get-AzureRmWebApp`.

Comment: Oh, good grief. Just when I thought that upgrading to Premium V2 was going to *solve* my troubles... :-(