# How do I deploy to Azure App Service with PowerShell (az module)?

Tags: azure, powershell, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service

I want to deploy app services from Powershell.
I would like to use only publish profile (no password for azure account).

I tried `FTP` service, but sometimes files are blocked by running users.
I think I have to stop app service.

There is powershell command like:

```
Publish-AzWebApp
```

However first I need login with:

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

and pass credentials what I want to avoid.

**There is any way to call `Publish-AzWebApp` based on only publish profile (no login by account)?**

`Connect-AzAccount` has other options to login (token or certificate).
Unfortunately I don't know how to generate it.

BTW There was a topic about it:
[How do I deploy to Azure App Service with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849917/how-do-i-deploy-to-azure-app-service-with-powershell)
But it is old and now module "az" is recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is any way to call Publish-AzWebApp based on only publish profile (no login by account)?

No, you can't. If you want to use the `Publish-AzWebApp` , you always need to login with `Connect-AzAccount`, whatever the parameters you use, examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/Connect-AzAccount?view=azps-2.5.0#examples).

If you want to use powershell to deploy the web app based on only publish profile, the workaround is to [use Kudu API via powershell](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#sample-of-using-rest-api-with-powershell).

```
$username = "`$webappname"
$password = "xxxxxxx"
# Note that the $username here should look like `SomeUserName`, and **not** `SomeSite\SomeUserName`
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"

$apiUrl = "https://joywebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"
$filePath = "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\testdep.zip"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-2.5.0#sign-in-with-a-service-principal-

[image]

Comment: Yes, I installed this module already, and I have never install AzureRM.

Comment: Hi @Bytezar, I'm sorry for the misunderstand. I have updated the answer. Please take a look. I saw there is another solution provided by Joy Wang. You can choose the solution whichever of the two you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step by step process of deploying and publishing an Azure app service with PowerShell (PS) using newly recommended [Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-6.6.0). You'll have to install [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli) before running the scripts:

```
$subscription = 'Visual Studio Enterprise – MPN' #Change it as per your Azure subscription
$location = 'Central US' #Change it according to the location where you want to host your web app
$resourceGroup = 'MyWebAppResourceGroup'

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" #this ensures that script stops executing at first error in the script.


Write-host "Installing nuget package provider"
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Scope CurrentUser -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
Write-Host "Setting Power Shell gallery"
Set-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" -InstallationPolicy Trusted

Write-Host "Installing missing PowerShell modules required for running this script.."
if ((Get-InstalledModule -Name "Az.Accounts" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "Az.Accounts module missing. Now installing..."
    Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -Scope CurrentUser
}


if ((Get-InstalledModule -Name "Az.Websites" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "Az.Websites module missing. Now installing .."
    Install-Module -Name Az.Websites -Scope CurrentUser
}
Write-Host "Installing PowerShell modules completed."

Write-Host "Staring to import PowerShell modules in current session...."
Import-Module Az.websites
Write-Host "Importing PowerShell modules completed."


#This is required due to an issue due to which PowerShell fails to connect with online resources. This issue is machine specific. So you can comment it if not required.
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Write-Host "Connecting to Azure account..."
Connect-AzAccount 

Write-Host "Setting subscription for current session..."
az account set --subscription $subscription

Write-Host "Creating resource group..."
az group create --name $resourceGroup --location $location

$webAppName="WelcomeCloudApp"  
$appServicePlan="WelcomeCloudAppServicePlan"  

Write-Host "Creating WebApp Service plan..."
New-AzAppServicePlan  -Name $appServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup  -Location $location -Tier 'Free' #-Debug  

Write-Host "Creating WebApp..."
New-AzWebApp -Name $webAppName -Location $location -AppServicePlan $appServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup 

Write-Host "Publishing WebApp..."
Publish-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $webAppName -ArchivePath WelcomeCloudAppService.zip  

Write-Host "Finished installing your web app. Bye!"
```